# Delete occurrences of atom from list - LISP

Tags: lisp

I am new to LISP, here I am trying to remove all occurrences of an atom from a list -

my code so far -

```
(defun rematom (A LAT)
   (cond
      ((null LAT) ())
      ((EQ (car LAT) A car LAT))
      (T (cons (car LAT)(rematom, A (cdr LAT))))
)))
```

This code is removing the first occurrence of the element, how can I remove all occurrences?

My output -

```
> (rematom 'a '(a b c a d a))
(B C A D A)
```

Desired -

```
>(rematom 'a '(a b c a d a))
(B C D)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is T here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second case should call rematom:

```
  ((EQ (car LAT) A) (rematom A (cdr LAT)))
```

Only the first case, the base case that checks for an empty list, should be non recursive. The others here need to call rematom recursively.

Comment: ((EQ (car LAT) A) (rematom A (cdr LAT))), yep this solved it, thanks so much for the help.